# Change pagination based on user type with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I try to set the pagination of my WebAPI based on the status of a User. If the user `is_anonymous` he should not be able to set the page size with a query parameter. I try to do this with one view class. I could do it with two different view classes and limit the access to one of them, but I think this is not a good solution.

View Class:

```
class WeathermList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = WeatherMeasurements.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WeatherMeasurementsSer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = WeatherMeasurementsFilter
    ordering_fields = ('measure_datetime',)
    ordering = ('measure_datetime',)

    @property
    def paginator(self):
        """
        The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            # import ipdb
            # ipdb.set_trace()
            if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
                self._paginator = AnonymousPaginator
            else:
                self._paginator = RegisteredPaginator
        return self._paginator
```

Pagination classes:

```
class RegisteredPaginator(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 288
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000


class AnonymousPaginator(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 288
```

Error message:

```
File ".../env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 172, in paginate_queryset
    return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
TypeError: paginate_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

The `property paginator` is originally declared in class [GenericAPIView](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/67ac0486f504d957fd123c8b913fb93a71cacdcd/rest_framework/generics.py). I am not sure if I reimplement it correctly. Both Custom pagination classes of mine are working when I set them using `pagination_class`

Any help to get this working is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: `self._paginator` needs a paginator class instance, not a class itself

It should be  `AnonymousPaginator()`and `RegisteredPaginator()`, not `AnonymousPaginator`, `RegisteredPaginator`.

```
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            self._paginator = AnonymousPaginator()
        else:
            self._paginator = RegisteredPaginator()
```

Comment: Oh my god, how embarrassing. Thank you very much! Do you think it is a good idea to use pagination like this?

Comment: @ChristianRapp yep, in fact, that is the best way to do it. In fact, I recommended that approach just few hours ago in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988272/django-rest-framework-drf-how-to-set-pagination-class-depending-on-query-param/38989390#38989390